# How to retrieve Medium posts for a user real time?

Tags: web-scraping, graphql, medium.com-publishing-api

I am trying to get Medium user posts real time. I tried:

```
https://medium.com/feed/@your_profile
```

```
https://medium.com/@yourhandle/latest?format=json
```

However, I'm getting several minutes cached reply back based on firstPublishedAt param in JSON response. I need to be able to get user posts as soon as they are posted.
Any advice how to achieve that?